# How to implement json format logs in python

Tags: python, json, logging

I have a below piece of code for python logging and would want to convert the logs into json format for better accessibility of information. How can I convert them into JSON format?

```
import os
import logging

log_fmt = ("%(asctime)-s %(levelname)-s %(message)s")

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'))

logger.info(f"this is a test")
```

And the output looks like `"2022-04-20 17:40:31,332 INFO this is a test"`

How can I format this into a json object so I can access by keys?
Desired output:

```
{
 "time": "2022-04-20 17:40:31,332",
 "level": "INFO",
 "message": "this is a test"
}
```

Comment: A search for "python logging json" results in several possible solutions. Did none of these work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Python JSON Logger](https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/)

But if you don't want to, or can't do that, then your log format string should be...

```
log_fmt = ("{\"time\": %(asctime)-s, \"level\": %(levelname)-s, \"message\": %(message)s},")
```

You'll end up with an extra comma at the end of the log file that you can programatically remove later. Or, you can do this if you want the comma at the top of the file...

```
log_fmt = (",{\"time\": %(asctime)-s, \"level\": %(levelname)-s, \"message\": %(message)s}")
```

But the json will look better in an editor with the comma at the end of every line.

If you provide a mechanism for users to download, or otherwise access log files, then you can do the trailing comma cleanup there, before you send the log file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could also design a simple formatter like this one (which basically create a dictionary and serialises it to JSON format):

```
import json
import logging


class JsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Formatter to dump error message into JSON"""

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        record_dict = {
            "level": record.levelname,
            "date": self.formatTime(record),
            "message": record.getMessage(),
            "module": record.module,
            "lineno": record.lineno,
        }
        return json.dumps(record_dict)
```

Here is an example on how to use it if you want just warnings and errors, and then loads them back in a pandas DataFrame.

```
import logging

import pandas as pd

logger = logging.getLogger()

json_h = logging.FileHandler("errors.ndjson", mode="w")
formatter = JsonFormatter()
json_h.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(json_h)

logger.error("""some error with "double quotes" and 'single quotes'""")
logger.critical("some critical text")
logger.warning("some warning")
logger.info("some info that shall not appear")

df = pd.read_json("errors.ndjson", lines=True)
print(df.dtypes)  # type: ignore
print(df)
```

As mentioned by Phillip H. BLanton, you coud also use [Python JSON Logger](https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/):

```
...
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger


log_format = "%(asctime)s - %(module)s#%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
    fmt=log_format, rename_fields={"levelname": "level", "asctime": "date"}
)

logger = logging.getLogger()

json_h= logging.FileHandler("errors.ndjson", mode="w")
json_h.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(json_h)
...
```

Note that the simple implementation has the following limitations compared to `python-json-logger`:

- a hard-coded choice of attributes (but this could be parametrized via an argument of the Formatter class)
- no support of Traceback / Exception (i.e. `exc_info`)
- does not display `extra` information (like for example in `logger.info("message", extra={"field": "value"}`)